# Проблема с модулем сетевой карты rtl8821ce

Tags: ubuntu

Не понимаю почему, но в один день у меня перестал работать интернет на Ubuntu 20.04. К wifi подключается, но интернета нету, и вместо иконки скорости висит иконка с вопросом. Причем к точке доступа с телефона он подключается и работает нормально. Но дело вряд-ли в роутере, потому что остальная техника подключается к нему и работает нормально.

1. Я пробовал **sudo apt update** и **sudo apt upgrade**, но это не помогло
2. Тогда я посмотрел какие модули сетевой карты сейчас загружены **sudo lsmod | grep 8821** и это выдало:

```
8821ce               1998848  0
cfg80211              983040  1 8821ce
```

Я удалил их: **sudo rmmod 8821ce**, **sudo apt purge rtl8821ce-dkms**, **sudo apt purge rtl8821ce-dkms**
и попытался установить заново: **sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms**, на что получил:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
  rtl8821ce-dkms
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 1 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 22 пакетов не обновлено.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/2 197 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 25,2 MB.
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета rtl8821ce-dkms.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 181324 файла и каталога.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.4_all.deb …
Распаковывается rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.4) …
Настраивается пакет rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.4) …
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64 is 
not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64 
(x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 10
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 rtl8821ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

3. Попробовал **sudo dpkg --configure -a**, **sudo apt-get install -f**, **sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/rtl8821ce-dkms***, но ничего из этого не помогло
4. Тут я подумал, что может быть проблема с этим пакетом и попытался установить прошлой версию **sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms=5.5.2.1-0ubuntu3** и это выдало:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Следующие пакеты будут заменены на СТАРЫЕ версии:
  rtl8821ce-dkms
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, 1 пакетов заменено на старые версии, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 22 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 1 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/2 196 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства уменьшится на 2 048 B.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] д
dpkg: предупреждение: снижение версии rtl8821ce-dkms с 5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.4 до 5.5.2.1-0ubuntu3
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 181983 файла и каталога.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb …

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.5.2.1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Распаковывается rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu3) на замену (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.4) …
Настраивается пакет rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu3) …
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64 is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 rtl8821ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

5. Когда я пытаюсь установить драйвер через приложение **драйверы**, то получаю:

```
pk-clien-error-quark: Error while installing package: installen rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installatoin script subprocess returned error exit status 10 (313)
```

Еще я читал, что проблема может быть со свободным пространством в **/boot partition** и его можно очистить удалив старые ядра, но вручную я это делать боюсь. Может есть какой то вариант решить эту проблему.

Comment: Текст ошибки как бы намекает, что у вас ядро левое

Comment: Нет, ядро я не менял

Comment: Тем не менее по каким-то причинам оно теперь считается левым, раз текст ошибки на него ругается

Comment: получается надо менять ядро?

Comment: Как не менял, если ты лазил на https://liquorix.net/ ?

Comment: @donRumata, точно! Я уже и забыл про это, сейчас удалил все ядра liquorix и все работает!

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем проблема оказывается в том, что у меня стоит ядро **liquorix**. Перезагрузил систему в grub режиме, нажал на **Дополнительные параметры загрузки** и выбрал любое ядро, у которого в названии нет **liquorix**. После загрузки системы в терминале прописал `sudo apt purge *-liquorix-*` и тем самым удалил все zen-ядра. Ну и потом уже поставил модуль для сетевой карты: **sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms** и все заработало!